# Вписываются ли головы в синекдоху?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, тропы

Из окон время от времени выглядывали ворчливые женские головы, громогласно обсуждавшие, стоит ли вывешивать белье на просушку в этакую непогодь. Поплакавшись на слякотную осень и на всеобщее невезение, головы в эти же окна прятались. Звездочет бургомистра обещал на завтра вёдро - скорее всего, ошибался: так что если не удастся просохнуть, то можно будет хотя бы поругаться.

Можно так выразительно выражаться или это зюмо некузяво?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вписываются. Кузяво, зюмо даже можно так выражаться.
В [**Большом вопросе**](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/81727-chto-takoe-sinekdoha-primery-sinekdohi.html) эта тема довольно обстоятельно обсуждалась, и там есть похожий пример:
*В проеме показалась рыжая голова с большим белым бантом* (рыжая голова — это часть, а подразумевается маленькая девочка).

Я бы убрала в первом предложении "просушку": в непогодь уже все равно — сушим или проветриваем.
Поменяла бы "обещал" на "пообещал" — так меньше конкретики ("если бы да кабы" следуют потом).
"Процесс сушки" обозначила бы в последней части, можно использовать абстрактное "ничто".

Итак, получилось (может, подойдет?):

Из окон время от времени выглядывали ворчливые женские головы, громогласно обсуждавшие, стоит ли вывешивать белье в этакую непогодь. Поплакавшись на слякотную осень и на всеобщее невезение, головы в эти же окна прятались. Звездочет бургомистра пообещал на завтра вёдро — даже если ошибся и белью не удастся просохнуть, то можно будет хотя бы поругаться.

Или:
...даже если ошибся и ничто не просохнет, то можно будет хотя бы поругаться.

Comment: Тонко подмечно. Просушку лучше убрать. "Вывешивать белье на просушку" можно даже считать плеоназмом (для чего еще вывешивают белье?). А в данном случае есть только надежда на то, что белье просохнет.

Comment: По поводу  "если белью не удастся просохнуть". Нет последовательности в повествовании. Я понял, что, поговорив о погоде, никто белье так и не повесил. Тогда чему не удастся просохнуть?  Речь о том, чтобы вывесить белье завтра?

Comment: Да, сегодня никто белье так  и не повесил. Вся надежда на следующий день — звездочет пообещал вёдро. А вот завтра —  или будем сохнуть, или будем ругаться, поминая и звездочета, и непогодь, и мокрое белье. Я вижу так.

Comment: "Будем сохнуть" в смысле "будем сушить белье"? Спорно. Будем вывешивать белье или будем ругаться" - другое дело.

Comment: А, придумал! *Если не удастся просушить белье, то можно будет хотя бы поругаться.*

Comment: Так я об этом и написала в ответе: _даже если ошибся и белью не удастся просохнуть_. А "будем сохнуть" — это иносказательно; конечно же —  "сушить белье".

Comment: "Если не удастся просушить белье, то можно будет хотя бы поругаться". Автор утащил, весело напевая.

Answer (score 3):

Выразительно выражаться нужно! А не "можно". :) Хороший слог. Одно "но" - "белье на просушку", и тут же - "удастся просохнуть". Первое относится к неодушевлённому предмету. Второе - к одушевлённому. Такой оборот речи хорошо смотрится в"комичном "сюр-фентези". И в сказке типа "Муммитроллей", где можно применить просторечно-комичный язык.

Comment: Согласен и хочу добавить, что из контекста совсем не ясно, промокли ли "головы" и почему им нужно просохнуть.

Answer (score 2):

Против голов ничего не имею, но:
 - Звездочет **ошибся** один раз или **ошибался** несколько раз?
 - Мне непонятны причины постановки тире и двоеточия.
Я бы написал так:
**Звездочет бургомистра обещал на завтра вёдро, но, скорее всего, ошибся <запятая или тире> так что если не удастся `просушить белье`, то можно будет хотя бы поругаться.**